# NULL value on LEFT JOIN operation

Tags: mysql

Consider two tables:

```
•   draft_procedures
•   incoterms
```

Table **draft_procedures** has column

```
1.  incoterm
```

Table **incoterm** has column

```
 1. incotermUNIQUE
 2. incoterm_desc
```

Im trying to join up the two tables in order to get incoterm_desc (description) from incoterm table of draft_procedures incoterm.

When I use the following query I get a c3incoterm_desc NULL value

```
SELECT drp.incoterm, c3.incoterm_desc as c3incoterm_desc
FROM draft_procedures AS drp
LEFT JOIN incoterms AS c3 ON drp.incoterm = c3.incotermUNIQUE
```

Comment: That is what a `LEFT JOIN` is *supposed* to do.  What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to get the text description of the incoterm from incoterms table. table draft have column 'incoterm' with internal reference that is also on table 'incoterms' as incotermUNIQUE column.  incoterm.incoterm_desc has the text description

Comment: Your query does that.  You get `NULL` when there is no match.

Comment: Believe it or not Gordon, your comment help me out with the solution. One of the columns is truncating the last two characters leading to a no match. Im feeling bad with such a non-sense question. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

LEFT OUTER JOIN:
As per the Definition,LEFT OUTER JOIN retrieves rows from TableA (draft_procedures) with matching records from TableB (incoterms)
 **If for a certain record from TableA (left), there are no matching records from TableB (right), the corresponding (right) columns contain nulls**.

Select *
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
on TableA.name = TableB.name;